# Hide field in Add/Edit/Display Form

Tags: 2013, custom-form

I need to hide some fields in a Add/Edit/Display Form.  I believe this can be done via some HTML in the form?  I have only done this once and cannot remember how I did it last time.  I am currently editing the form in SP designer.

Comment: Javascript please

Comment: Hi Mike a similar question has been answer at below link http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/77986/hide-some-fields-in-the-newform-aspx-for-a-custom-list

Answer (score 1):

Just create new forms in Designer and delete what you don't want displayed.  Be sure they aren't required fields that aren't answered yet, or you'll get errors, but it's super simple.

Answer (score 0):

I found some notes I made.  This code solves my issue.`<tr style="display:none"><tr>`