# Hide Column in List on NewForm

Tags: list-form, hide-elements

I want to hide a column on the **NewForm** of a list but it should be **visible on the EditForm**.

How to do this?

Comment: Use JSLink to hide column in newform.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide fields using PowerShell in either newform, editform or viewform:

```
$fld = $list.Fields["HideThisField"]
$fld.ShowInNewForm = $false
$fld.Update()
```

Comment: Where to add this code? i am new to sharepoint. I can check NewForm.aspx and EditForm.aspx

Comment: Actually have a look at http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/77986/hide-some-fields-in-the-newform-aspx-for-a-custom-list Lots of different methods to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your Web URL is http://server/sites/site01/sub01, and your list is at http://server/sites/site01/sub01/lists/list01. Your field display name is "My Field to Hide".

If you have access to the SharePoint server, the best approach would be to set the field as hidden in new forms, as follow:

1. Log on the SP server
2. Launch a SharePoint Management Shell from Start menu
3. Enter the following code (line by line, replace values with your own's):

   ```
   $web = Get-SPWeb http://server/sites/site01/sub01
   $list = $web.Lists["http://server/sites/site01/sub01/lists/list01"]
   $field = $list.Fields["My Field to Hide"]
   $field.ShowInNewForm = $false
   $field.Update()
   ```

Comment: I am using sharepoint from office 365. No SP Server